# È corretto dire "il giro di un film"?

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary

È corretto dire "il giro di un film"? Se questa espressione non si usa in italiano, come si può esprimere l'azione di girare un film?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Il giro di un film** non è corretto, perché il sostantivo **[giro](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/G/giro.shtml)** non ha sempre lo stesso significato del verbo **[girare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/G/girare.shtml)**.

Questa espressione è corretta utilizzando un altro sostantivo, per esempio **le riprese di un film** o **la registrazione di un film**.

Comment: Un film si riprende, ma credo a più riprese, forse è più corretto usare il plurale: "le riprese di un film" o "la ripresa di una scena".

Comment: Confermo “riprese” al plurale, mentre “registrazione” suona un po' strano anche da quando si usano per lo più supporti digitali.

Comment: _Registrazione_ forse è più adatto alla ripresa di una puntata di una serie televisiva. Di sicuro non si usa per la pellicola, ma non credo che ci sia ancora chi al giorno d'oggi usi la pellicola. Si è usato però per supporti non digitali come il Betamax in campo professionale e il VHS in campo dilettantistico, ma la _registrazione di un film_ rimane un'espressione molto tecnica.

Answer (score 2):

Corretta la risposta di XDrake99. Aggiungerei che, se non hai necessità di usare un vero sostantivo, anche il verbo sostantivato può andare bene. Ad esempio:

*Mi sono sempre chiesto quanto possa costare **girare** un film*.

Si può anche usare con l'articolo, anche se può sembrare un po' più formale:

***Il girare*** un film d'azione comporta sempre dei rischi elevati per le controfigure.